# HRNG - Human Random Number Generator

Tags: popularity-contest, random

You know it: keyboard or mouse input is just too mainstream to create Random Numbers through human behavior.

Create the most unique (Pseudo)Random Number Generator that create its numbers through human behavior.

Web-API's are not restricted! Anyone should use the code provided, so any special hardware is restricted. (I think we can assume that everyone has a smartphone)
The number should be a 256 bit number.

Example: use the Google Map's API to get current traffic to create the Random Number.

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so most votes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38046/improvise-a-hardware-random-number-generator), possibly duplicate?

Comment: Related but no Duplicate. It restrict to Internet Access and use any item laying around. The Point what here should use: anyone should use the code without special hardware.

Comment: Can I use `random` on the data I gathered or it has to be purely independent of the in built `random` function of my language?

Comment: So, should it be heavily biased toward red hammers?

Comment: Aaron red hammers? hashcode55: you can, but it would be not so good for a human based random number generator ;) Qwerp-Derp: what is a reasonable length? End of February?

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica on Mac OS X

```
Mod[Tr /@ IntegerDigits[
  Floor[2^15 AudioData@SystemDialogInput@"RecordSound"]
, 2], 2]
```

Opens up a dialog box that lets you record a sound snippet through the computer's microphone, then converts the resulting digital audio data to a list of bits (roughly 50,000 bits per second of audio). Generate random numbers through white noise, singing your favorite tune, exclaiming "Serenity now!", or just yelling at the top of your lungs!

Comment: Will give +1 if you send a vid link of you running it and yelling really loud

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3

```python
import urllib.request
t=0
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109658/hrng-human-random-number-generator#109658") as f:
    m = f.read().decode("utf8")
    for c in m:
        t+=ord(c)
print(t/len(m.split()))
```

This version takes each characters ordinals to take into account changing values such as votes.

Leaving the below in as it was my first attempt but as noted it is a little stale.

```python
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109658/hrng-human-random-number-generator#109658") as f:
    m = f.read().decode("utf8")
print(len(m)/len(m.split()))
```

Takes this current page gets it's character count and word count divides and returns the number.

Not sure if it's great but first idea that came to mind.

Comment: +1 I really like this answer! Though, it won't update too often haha. A more frequently updating answer could be taking the hash of the page and converting it to numeric form (using modulo and others) because then you get all of the minor changes as well (changes that dont increase character count) such as any user here getting reputation. Any timestamp updating. etc

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw - Thank you :D - That change of course would be a much better way for me to do it, I'll have a look at a changing it when I get back on a proper computer (using mobile atm).

Answer (score 2):

## Bash

```
w|sha256sum|tr -d -
```

Outputs a hex-encoded 256 bit "random" number

> **w**  displays information about the users currently on the machine, and their processes.  The header shows, in this order, the current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

[Try It Online !](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVXhoMlhIS1lnRms)

Comment: @FlipTack, yep, just a habit :)